# Question involving Galois Extension

Tags: galois-theory, extension-field, galois-extensions

Let $K$ be a field with characteristic $p \neq 0$. Let $L:K$ be a cyclic extension s.t $[L:K]=p^s, s>1$. Show that there exists a field $F$ s.t $K \subset F \subset L$, $[F:K]=p^{s-1}$ and $F:K$ is cyclic.

$\textbf{My attempt:}$

Since $L:K$ is galois (because it is cyclic) we have $|Gal(L/K)|=p^s$. Now, by Cauchy's theorem, there is a subgrup H of $Gal(L/K)$ s.t $|H|= p$.  Take $F = L^H$, since $L:K$ is galois we have $L:F$ galois and $[L:F] = p$. Therefore, $[F:K]=p^{s-1}$ and since $Gal(L/K)$ is cyclic, we have $Gal(F/K)$ cyclic.

My only question is, how can I prove that $F:K$ is normal??

Comment: Not my area really but isn't this because the groups corresponding to $p^{s}$, $p^{s-1}$,... is in a chain of Sylow subgroups which all are normal? Assuming p is a prime.

Comment: I don't know that result. There is a easiest way to prove that $H$ is normal?

Comment: Your hypothesis on $L/K$ means that it is a galois extension with Galois group G cyclic of order $p^s$ (if not, what is your definition of a "cyclic extension" ?). Thus G is abelian, in particular all subgroups of G are normal. Note that for any $n \le s$, the cyclic group G admits a *unique* subgroup of order $p^n$.